# Is this philosophical question acceptable?

Tags: discussion

Is this even remotely acceptable? Thank you.

> *Background*: I am a 30 year old undergraduate at a college majoring in
>   mathematics with goal of specializing in philosophical aspects of it.
>   There are certain books and theories that has affected my personal
>   philosophy which made me a skeptic (mathematical atheist if you will).
>   One such book was Keith Devlin's "Goodbye Descartes: End of Logic"
>   along with Wittgenstein final nail that "Whereof one cannot speak,
>   thereof one must be silent." This was 8 years ago and then I came
>   across Kurt Godel's proof and Raymond Smullyan's books. Latter's
>   Taoist philosophy attracted me greatly. Also I delved into Zen
>   Buddhist literature and Hofstadter. Zen encourages to maintain a
>   beginner's mind and to question everything. So when I meditate on
>   logic itself and dig further 'down the rabbit hole' it appears that
>   mathematics is actually based on assumptions or axioms or formally ZF
>   or ZFC. Why is 2+2=4? One can show Russell and Whitehead's proof which
>   further begs what is the foundational 'glue' of logical connectives or
>   what is the formal definition of entailment? As I studied further I
>   came upon Non-well founded set theory, concept of predicativity,
>   relativity of structures, randomness, algorithmic information theory,
>   Chaitin's conclusion *mathematics is random* which further ossified my
>   beliefs that mathematics may be based on 'beliefs' or 'assumptions'.
>   In passing I allude that I enrolled back in college and registered in
>   a Contemporary Philosophy class where (controversial according to
>   some) "What the BLEEP do we know?" was shown.
>
> *Personal philosophy*: I apologize if I am asking for a silver bullet
>   for answers of all the philoso-mathematical problems. I am actually
>   lost. I do not know where to begin. When I was a child I used to labor
>   over problems, solve them and check the answers to the 'correct'
>   solution. However at this stage of my life I find no motivation
>   because I do not know what I know or what we can know or where to even
>   start. Naively after inner meditations I come to the conclusion that
>   mathematics must be a quasi-empirical science or subject based upon
>   assumptions. Further to confuse and muddle my thinking, I read Field's
>   fictionalism, Banach-Tarski paradox, Brouwer's intuitionist ideas, anthropological beliefs,
>   smattering of New Age quantum mechanical popular books, idea of
>   digital physics and all paths seem to inevitable point to the a
>   conclusion that it could be based upon 'thin air'. It appears that what  appeared to be air tight logic is actually full of paradoxes, circularity and relativity.
>
> *Question*: Is the aforementioned conclusion or observation valid or
>   sound?

Comment: It is interesting, but I think it is too subjective for this site.

Comment: Can it be perhaps transferred to Philosophy.stackexchange? Or should I delete it and start a new discussion over there instead? (Additionally, I fear what if they point back back to this site for answer?)

Comment: "Additionally, I fear what if they point back back to this site for answer?" - you should mention that you've asked here at this site's meta site in the comments...

Comment: Thank you. I just did.

Comment: @Zeeshan Just out of curiosity, could you add a link to the question in philosophy.SE?  Thanks.

Comment: @Srivatsan Here you go [link](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/1848/is-mathematics-founded-on-beliefs-and-assumptions)